# What is table attribute in Magento database?

Tags: database, extensions, table

I have an extension and on the backend it gives me an option of adding percentage based surcharge on subtotal. For one of the field it says:

> Please enter an `sales_flat_quote_address` attribute code which will be
>   taken as base for the cost calculation.

Now as far as I know, `sales_flat_quote_address` is the name of a table in Magento database which holders user information.How do I get this table's attribute code?

I have mailed the extension developers but there is no response :(

Comment: @kiatng could you be more specific please?

Comment: I couldn't post the specific because stackexachange complains that it is too long to add as comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL statement to get the *attribute codes* is `describe sales_flat_quote_address`. I did that for you and here is the list of relevant *attribute codes*:

> subtotal
>   base_subtotal
>   subtotal_with_discount
>   base_subtotal_with_discount
>   tax_amount
>   base_tax_amount
>   shipping_amount
>   base_shipping_amount
>   shipping_tax_amount
>   base_shipping_tax_amount
>   discount_amount
>   base_discount_amount
>   grand_total
>   base_grand_total
>   shipping_discount_amount
>   base_shipping_discount_amount
>   subtotal_incl_tax
>   base_subtotal_total_incl_tax
>   hidden_tax_amount
>   base_hidden_tax_amount
>   shipping_hidden_tax_amount
>   base_shipping_hidden_tax_amnt
>   shipping_incl_tax
>   base_shipping_incl_tax

Comment: Thanks a million for the effort.Please tell me too where you executed this statement. Is it in sales_flat_quote_address table ?

Comment: It is a MySQL statement, meaning you need to execute it there or in PHPMyAdmin or something similar.